# Загрузка файлов на сервер Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, vps

Как загрузить файлы на VPS-сервер (если можно, то через noVNC) из windows 10

Comment: Зачем гуй, если можно `FileZilla`, `WinSCP`?

Comment: Зачем загружать файлы, если можно прикрутить репозиторий?